# character encoding windows 1251 nor utf8 displays menu in RU correctly

Tags: character-encoding

Just changing the encoding to windows-1251 for http://tinyurl.com/6m2lp6m It did not help. Reverted to it as uft8 was not working for that page. The menu still looks like crap. All Russian characters on all pages are also not displayed in Russian on my laptop's TextMate editor. It is jus gibberish. Why is that?  I am guessing it is because I am using file encoding in utf8. Am I right? How can I convert all to utf8 and get rid of Windows 1251?

Comment: How is it displayed in TextMate? How are you saving it from TextMate?

Comment: In TextMate I save as utf8 and I see Г›пЈїГ’Лљ вЂЎГЊвЂћГЋГ‹Г€Г’ГЌГ“вЂћГ“ Л‡ГЃЛљГЌвЂЎ. Е“Г“вЂ°вЂћГ“ГљГ“вЂљГЌвЂЎ ГЌ ЛќГЌГЃвЂЎГЏГ‚ГЊвЂЎГЏ instead of Russian in TextMate

Comment: So it's already screwed up when opening it in TextMate. You first need to open the file in the correct encoding (File > Reopen using encoding...), then save it using your desired encoding. I don't know/think TextMate can handle the 1251 encoding though. Try [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) instead to convert the file, it can handle a lot more encodings. If there's no text editor that can handle your encoding, use `iconv` on the command line to convert the file.